# 'Microsoft::WRL::FtmBase' class has virtual functions, but destructor is not virtual

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, visual-c++, wrl

I'm getting this compile error

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows
>   Kits\10\include\10.0.17134.0\winrt\wrl\implements.h(1453): warning
>   C4265: 'Microsoft::WRL::FtmBase': class has virtual functions, but
>   destructor is not virtual

after adding "#include < wrl.h>" to my program. I'm using /W4 flag. Is there something that I'm missing here? some kind of macro that needs to be defined? Curious if there's a way to fix that warning without suppressing it.

Also, I'm using latest VS 2017 with c++17 if that helps.

Comment: If a class has virtual methods, it is expecting to be a base class that can be derived from so those methods can be overridden. A base class without a virtual destructor is dangerous, as calling `delete` on a base class pointer will not call any derived class destructors. Sounds like an oversight on MS's part, unless `delete` is *never* called on a `FmtBase*` pointer (ie, if `FmtBase`-derived objects are *never* constructed with `new`), if `FmtBase*` pointers are *always* casted to a derived type before `delete` is called, or if a `FmtBase`-derived object calls its own destructor when released

Comment: yea, very weird. I was interested in using the ComPtr class, and it seems that instead of including wrl.h, i can include #include <wrl/client.h> which doesn't have that warning

Comment: `FtmBase` is used by `RuntimeClass` which should never be `delete`d. It should be `Release`d.